# How can I convert a module.exports and map(require.resolve) into an actual file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the airbnb eslint config loading from many files using some legacy common js module stuff I don't understand.

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    './eslint-rules/best-practices',
    './eslint-rules/errors',
    './eslint-rules/node',
    './eslint-rules/style',
    './eslint-rules/variables',
    './eslint-rules/es6',
    // './eslint-rules/imports',
  ].map(require.resolve),
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    strict: 'error',
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    mocha: true,
  },
};
```

I would like to export the result of all this as a single .JSON file that I can include in my package.json file to avoid bloat and multiple files hiding everywhere. Regardless if you think this is a thing worth doing, can it be done?

I am hoping there is a simple way using `const fs = require('fs');` , but I am not an expert in Node and work only in the browser.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. `package.json` is just that--a JSON file. Not a JS file.

Comment: It is a JSON file used by NPM and various software as a kind of central config for all things JS. I found this quote "The package.json is used as what equates to a manifest about applications, modules, packages, and more - it's a tool to that's used to make modern development streamlined, modular, and efficient."

Comment: Correct. A JSON file. Not a code file.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring "Configuration Files - use a JavaScript, JSON or YAML file to specify configuration information for an entire directory (other than your home directory) and all of its subdirectories. This can be in the form of an .eslintrc.* file or an eslintConfig field in a package.json file, both of which ESLint will look for and read automatically..."

Comment: i made an edit to correct my js/json confused writing... thanks!

Comment: What I'm saying is that you cannot run code inside your package.json file, because it's a JSON file, not a code file. You could pre-process something to *create* your package.json file, but you cannot by default include other files like you're asking. Because it's a JSON file. Not code.

Comment: I agree, I want to concat all the eslint.js files (which export JSON I think?) into a big JSON file. Here is one https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/best-practices.js . Stackoverflow is telling me not to chat anymore in comments... any help gratefully received, I hope my request for help is clear now :)

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the issue is; you can specify `extends` in your `package.json`, e.g., https://gist.github.com/richardtallent/d4452bd0aa23020e999dd9410458df46.

Comment: The issue is I want to concatenate all the eslint files into ONE JSON file that I can copy/paste into my package.json file. I don't want multiple files everywhere, I don't want to update it for another year. I just want a standard package.json I can use for all my projects that contains my eslint config. It is doable as mentioned in the official docs I linked, it is just HOW I can make this file using the multiple eslint config files.